# Alocação Dinâmica de Memória em Cobol

Tags: memória, alocação, cobol

Como se aloca memória dinâmica em Cobol sem usar bibliotecas externas de C?

Não tenho interesse em usar algum tipo de `*alloc()` vindo do C. Em algum sabor de Cobol existe? Deve existir, pois se agora alguns compiladores possuem acesso a banco de dados, internet e POO, então pode ter. A pesquisa em inglês não me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O verbo em COBOL que faz isso é `ALLOCATE`. Atribuição de apenas pode ser usado com um item de dados definidos como `BASED` (o que indica que o compilador não atribuir o armazenamento habitual para o item de dados). `FREE` libertar o armazenamento obtido por alocar.

ALLOCATE / BASE / FREE existem desde o 2002 Standard que foi substituído pelo 2014 Standard. A implementação é para baixo para o fornecedor do compilador e nem todos os compiladores suportar isto.

Todos os COBOLs terá formas adicionais para alocar armazenamento atribuído a um valor de `POINTER` através de uma chamada de sistema de algum tipo.

Há também uma maneira de carregar, mas não executar, "um programa" que contém o armazenamento (geralmente para referência), utilizando um `PROCEDURE- POINTER` (ou um `FUNCTION-POINTER`).

`CALL` é usado em muitas maneiras de fazer muitas coisas, inclusive permitindo o acesso ao armazenamento fora do programa ativo no momento. Se algo não existe, você sempre pode escrever um programa e CALL ele.

Comment: Olá e obrigado por responder. Existe algum código de exemplo com todos estes comandos? Todas estas palavras-chave? Eu tenho o Stern & Stern mas parece-me que ele tem nada. Alguns livros de Cobol dos anos 80 não são uma boa escolha. Existe algum livro que fale disto? Eu suponho que exemplos de internet sejam melhores. Obrigado de novo.

Comment: Encontre o projeto GnuCOBOL (atualmente no SourceForge ) . Existem alguns exemplos lá . Pesquisar com as palavras-chave também deve localizá-los. I contribuir para esse projeto. , E há uma área de discussão ativa. Procure Guia de Programação do GnuCOBOL por Gary Cutler .